# How to open USB device in OSX

Tags: macos, usb, posix, device

I'm finally able to get the device path ("/dev/rdisk1") - called devname here - after a search but POSIX open() fails with -1. Is this a permission issue? The camera is mounted and can be read normally via /Volumes but I need to access via /dev to control the camera via USB tether.

```
/* Found PENTAX DIGITAL_CAMERA */
snprintf(pslr.devname, sizeof(pslr.devname), "%s", devpath);
pslr.devname[sizeof(pslr.devname)-1] = '\0';

printf("pslr.devname %s\n", pslr.devname);

pslr.fd = open(pslr.devname, O_RDWR);
if (pslr.fd == -1) {
    return NULL;
}
```

PS: after the discussion below I changed the permissions with sudo chmod command and then tried open but it still fails. I must be missing a step.

Comment: `/dev/rdisk1` seems unlikely to be a camera - be very careful!!!

Comment: Check the permissions on the devname with `ls` to see what they are.

Comment: Yeah, I think its the camera because it showed up when I plugged it in.

Comment: The permissions are : crw-r-----  1 root  operator    1,   5  9 Oct 14:14 /dev/rdisk1

Comment: So you will need `sudo` to open it for write.

Comment: :-) That was my next question! Thanks!

Comment: Please have a check with `diskutil list`

Comment: Hmm.. I get this which looks like i need rdisk1s1 which I got previously but now don't know how I got it.... /dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *16.1 GB    disk1
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 K-5 II                  16.1 GB    disk1s1

Comment: As long as `/dev/disk1` is your 16GB camera flash card, then anything you do on `/dev/rdisk1xx` will be fine. The `r` is just a raw character interface to the same thing and the `s1` is `slice1` which is the first partition on the disk.

Comment: The thing I don't get is that I know sudo in command line but this is objective-c code. Can I do a system call from objective-c code?

Comment: I found NSTask. I'll give that a try. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: If your compiled program is called `fred`, just run `sudo ./fred`.

Comment: OK. I'll give it a try but I plan to let others use this and I don't think it can be run in su mode in general.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with apple support and they say I cannot use posix functions to control a USB device in OS X.